# The entity type requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing an ASP.NET Web API right now and everything works just fine for 2 controllers. Now I try to do exactly the same as before but this time I get a weird error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "The entity type 'UserItem' requires a primary key to be defined."

Well then, why does `UserItem` needs a primary key when the others don't?

This is my `UserItem` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ModulApi.Models
{
    public class UserItem
    {
        public int matrikelnr { get; set; }
        public string studiengang { get; set; }
        public string user_semester { get; set; }
        public string user_max_klausur { get; set; }

        //Not necessary Constructor. I try to fix the primary Key error.
        public UserItem()
        {
            this.matrikelnr = 0;
            this.studiengang = "";
            this.user_max_klausur = "";
            this.user_semester = "";
        }
    }
}
```

And my WORKING `LoginItem` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ModulApi.Models
{
    public class LoginItem
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string matrikelnr { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string email_verified { get; set; }

        public LoginItem()
        {
            this.Id = 0;
            this.username = "";
            this.password = "";
            this.matrikelnr = "";
            this.email = "";
            this.email_verified = "";
         }
    }
}
```

As you see, I got getter and setter set up, so the error can't be there.

Here is where the error occurs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ModulApi.Models;
using ModulApi.DBConnectors;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit 
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace ModulApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/user")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserContext _context;

        public UserController(UserContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

            if (_context.UserItems.Count() == 0)  <--- Error right here
            {
                 getDataFromConnector(_context);
            }
        }

        private void getDataFromConnector(UserContext context)
        {
            //Getting my Data from Database method
        }
        .
        .
```

Well Since it is in a Context call, I'll attach UserContext as well, but again it is the same as in LoginContext, which works just fine.

UserContext:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ModulApi.Models
{
    public class UserContext : DbContext
    {
        public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserItem> UserItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Has anyone a clue why I get this weird error? And why all other Controllers work fine which do exactly the same?

Comment: EF sets LoginItem member Id as default primary key. Since no member Id or UserItemId is present in UserItem you get this error

Comment: may be in your database table you don't set the primary key

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Entity Framework goes by [convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx). That means that if you have an object with a property named `Id`, it will assume that it is the Primary Key for the object. That's why your `LoginItem`class works fine.

Your `UserItem` class has no such property, and therefor it can't figure out what to use as the primary key.

To fix this, affix the [KeyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to whatever your primary key is on your class. For example:

```
// Need to add the following using as well at the top of the file:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class UserItem
{
    [Key]
    public int matrikelnr { get; set; }
    public string studiengang { get; set; }
    public string user_semester { get; set; }
    public string user_max_klausur { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that work. But I also had to add "using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations"

Comment: Correct. That's why I linked the attribute so you can see everything about it, including the namespace. However, I will add that to the answer as well.

Comment: So, that means that you cannot use EF Core to map results from SPs to DTOs, without defining a primary key for them? Isn't this a bit weird? The Full framework EF could do this mapping without problems (`ctx.Database.SqlQuery<MyDTO>("dbo.MySP {0}", docId).FirstOrDefault();`).

Comment: @user2173353 I'm fairly certain you needed a PK in EF 5.0 (.NET Framework) as well. That code that you shared is running a manual query as opposed to using the `DbSet` properties on the Context that the question was asking about. For those queries, you can project it into any C# object that contains the properties you'll return from the Stored Procedure. You can still do that in EF Core.

Comment: I think in older versions of the EF, this was not a requirement.

Comment: @Fandango68 It's always been a requirement when your key doesn't follow convention. Without the attribute, or another approach to tell EF, it doesn't know how to find what the Primary Key is.

Comment: @krillgar - I was referring to it stopping you in the older versions. In .Net 4.5 I never had this problem or requirement to force a [Key]

Answer (score 9):

Your working `LoginItem` has:

```
public long Id { get; set; }
```

Properties called `*id` are detected and used as the primary key by convention. You need to explicitly set the `[Key]` attribute otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple was to resolve this.

1.Decorate  `matrikelnr` as `[Key]`

```
public class UserItem
{
    [Key]
    public int matrikelnr { get; set; }
    public string studiengang { get; set; }
    public string user_semester { get; set; }
    public string user_max_klausur { get; set; }

    //Not necessary Constructor. I try to fix the primary Key error.
    public UserItem()
    {
        this.matrikelnr = 0;
        this.studiengang = "";
        this.user_max_klausur = "";
        this.user_semester = "";
    }
}
```

2.Rename `matrikelnr` with `matrikelnrId` . With `*Id` , `EF` will consider it as `PK`.

```
 public class UserItem
{
    [Key]
    public int matrikelnrId { get; set; }
    public string studiengang { get; set; }
    public string user_semester { get; set; }
    public string user_max_klausur { get; set; }

    //Not necessary Constructor. I try to fix the primary Key error.
    public UserItem()
    {
        this.matrikelnrId = 0;
        this.studiengang = "";
        this.user_max_klausur = "";
        this.user_semester = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Beacuse you register UserItem with DBContext, DBContext Bind this user item with SQL database Table with which it is necessary to set any primary key attribute in UserItem.
Try this , it will resolve your problem.
[Key]
public int matrikelnr { get; set; }